# Angular Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I'm extending a class from a library https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker/

My class is:

```
export class DefaultIntl extends OwlDateTimeIntl {
  cancelBtnLabel: '';
  constructor(
    private translateService: TranslationService,
  ) {
    super();
    this.translateService
      .translateKey(CANCEL_BTN')
      .subscribe(message => {
        console.log('Message:' + message);
        this.cancelBtnLabel = message;
      });
  }
}
```

And the class that I'm extending in the library:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
export declare class OwlDateTimeIntl {
    readonly changes: Subject<void>;
    upSecondLabel: string;
    downSecondLabel: string;
    upMinuteLabel: string;
    downMinuteLabel: string;
    upHourLabel: string;
    downHourLabel: string;
    prevMonthLabel: string;
    nextMonthLabel: string;
    prevYearLabel: string;
    nextYearLabel: string;
    prevMultiYearLabel: string;
    nextMultiYearLabel: string;
    switchToMonthViewLabel: string;
    switchToMultiYearViewLabel: string;
    cancelBtnLabel: string;
    setBtnLabel: string;
    rangeFromLabel: string;
    rangeToLabel: string;
    hour12AMLabel: string;
    hour12PMLabel: string;
}
```

With this, I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DefaultIntl

My Translation service is:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Injectable()
export class TranslationService {
    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    }
    translateKey(key: string, param?: any){
          return this.translate.get(key, param);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: did you add `@Injectable()` to your service?

Comment: How are you importing the TranslationService? Please post the code of TranslationService.

Comment: @PierreDuc Service means OwlDateTimeIntl or DefaultIntl or Translation Service?

Comment: @Ritesh I've added code of translation service

Comment: @user5155835 you need to add it to your `DefaultIntl`, because it's injecting stuff in the constructor

Comment: try @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

Comment: @DPro where do I put this?

Comment: change the annotation of your service to this

Comment: @DPro TranslationService?

Comment: @PierreDuc Do you mean `@Injectable() export class DefaultIntl extends OwlDateTimeIntl {`

Comment: the problem is that the TranslationService is not provided in the module where your component resides. so you either do  @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root', }) or implicitly provide it in the corresponding module

Comment: yes, TranslationService

Comment: @user5155835 Yes.. why don't you just try to see if it works :)?

Comment: @PierreDuc Because its contracting since DPro is saying to have it in TranslationService whereas you are saying to have it in DefaultIntl

Comment: It needs to be in both, because both classes are injecting services in their constructor. If you want them to be available globally and not limited to a component or module, you should add `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`. This way it's also tree shakable

Comment: @PierreDuc hold on, the error is Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DefaultIntl. it means that TranslationService is not provided, as far as i understand DefaultIntl is a component, not a service?

Comment: @DPro DefaultIntl is a service

Comment: all services need to be marked as @Injectable if you want Angular to be able to inject them. @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) will solve all your problems for now

Answer (score 0):

Answear for this issue is hide amongs replays for question, and it's hard to find it.
Before class that override "OwlDateTimeIntl" annotation:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
```

need to be added.
Thanks to @DPro for answear.